# Can't send via serial communication, but can receive

Tags: c#, serial-port, barcode-scanner

The situation is I have a Honeywell N5683 barcode scanner and I am unable to send it commands in any serial communication program outside of the Honeywell EZConfig Scanning software.

Please note the scanner has many different configuration settings it can accept. See here: https://www.honeywellaidc.com/CatalogDocuments/N56XX-UG%20Rev%20C.pdf

The goal of this program is to send a software trigger instead of having to manually press the scan button. The program I have written so far is able to receive the data when the physical button is pressed, but is unable to currently send data via the `SerialPort` class in .NET. Please see code below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private SerialPort serialPort1 = new SerialPort("COM3", 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(scannerDataReceivedHandler);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // COM Settings
        serialPort1.RtsEnable = true;
        serialPort1.DtrEnable = false;

        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            serialPort1.Close();
        serialPort1.Open();
    }

    private void scannerDataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Scan Successful");
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        int bytes = sp.BytesToRead;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];
        sp.Read(buffer, 0, bytes);
        string bufferOutput;
        bufferOutput = ByteArrayToHexString(buffer);

        Console.WriteLine(bufferOutput);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // on
        //this is the string I send with the Honeywell Program = "PAPTPR";

        string toSend = "50 41 50 54 50 52";

        try
        {
            byte[] data = HexStringToByteArray(toSend);

            if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort1.Open();
            }

            serialPort1.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException)
        {
        }
    }

    // UTILITY
    private byte[] HexStringToByteArray(string s)
    {
        s = s.Replace(" ", "");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[s.Length / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i += 2)
            buffer[i / 2] = (byte)Convert.ToByte(s.Substring(i, 2), 16);
        return buffer;
    }

    private string ByteArrayToHexString(byte[] data)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(data.Length * 3);
        foreach (byte b in data)
            sb.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 16).PadLeft(2, '0').PadRight(3, ' '));
        return sb.ToString().ToUpper();
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of a successful command sent to the Honeywell N5683 in the Honeywell EZConfig application: 
[image]

Comment: You normally have to send an extra character to indicate the end of the command.  Try appending 0x0d and/or 0x0a (carriage return and/or line feed).  The kind you cannot see in a screenshot :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this did not seem to have an effect. I can also mention that even when I try to connect to the Honeywell scanner in PuTTY, I am unable to send, but only able read.

Comment: Is there an exception happening in button1_Click?  There's an empty catch that might be hiding something.

Comment: Okay it ended up being the carriage return character that needed to be send. Thanks Hans Passant! I sent 0x0d at the end of the byte array and all way well.